# is triggers create any performance issues in Production

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on project where i am getting logs or data feed from outside in CSV and DAT file we have SSIS Package configured.i just wanted to create Trigger on table to reconcile table count with File count if i create triggers is it lead to performance issue?

AVG CSV/DAT FILE COUNT IS 2.5 M Records

Comment: Trigger is not an option here.Can you elaborate your problem ?In SSIS you can use variable also

Answer (score 0):

Yes, triggers will reduce your system performance by locking the tables for longer time. It is always better to look for other alternate options like CDC or handling the it manually thru' stored procedures or some other way.